# Oracle - Count Function (Orders Sold By each employee)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

Having a problem figuring out how to display results that show 2 columns; one being the employee id and the second being the orders sold by that employee.

The 2 tables in question are `Employees` and `Orders`. The primary keys in each are called `EmployeeID` and `OrderID`. `Orders` has the foreign key `EmployeeID` in it. I am assuming I need to use the `COUNT` function to figure out how many orders there are in total, but the `JOIN` and finding out how to tie in the employee id with that has lost me.

All I have so far:

```
SELECT e.employeeid, COUNT(Orders) AS 'Count'
FROM Employees e
JOIN Orders o ON e.Employeeid = o.Employeeid
GROUP BY e.employeeid;
```

Comment: So the output from your code is wrong? Show us the output from your code and a sample of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: Maybe try this?
 ```
SELECT e.employeeid, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
    FROM Employees e LEFT JOIN Orders o ON e.Employeeid = o.Employeeid
    GROUP BY e.employeeid;
```

Comment: There really is no need for the join is there?   Why not just count directly from orders group by employeeID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a foreign key in the orders table why even look at employees unless you need something specific from Employees. I would just do something like this.

```
select employeeid, count(*) from Orders group by employeeid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is good, the only thing is you cannot count a table, so change `COUNT(Orders)` to `COUNT(o.*)` or `COUNT(o.OrderID)`:

```
SELECT e.employeeid, COUNT(o.OrderID) AS OrderCount
FROM Employees e
JOIN Orders o ON e.Employeeid = o.Employeeid
GROUP BY e.employeeid;
```

Using a keyword like `COUNT` as identifier is not recommended, so I change it to `OrcerCount`, but it will work with `'Count'` if you really wanted that.

This query will only give you the employees who have orders (at least one order). If you want to include employees who don't have any order, change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: When I try and run it like this I get the error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression, any ideas?

Comment: Copy the query exactly from answer. You shouldn't get such error.